# Deploy WEB Service Consumer module

Tags: deployment, wcf-client

We have recently added some functionality to our web site that requires adding a service reference to an api in an external domain.  Adding the reference to a VS2008 project createed a sub-folder in the "Service References" folder and added 18 files to that folder that appear to represent the classes in the api.  The api provider also had me add custom binding and client references to system.serviceModel in my web.config file.

Do I have to deploy that entire folder with its 18 files to my production site to use the web service?  Does some of it get compiled into my project dll? I can find all kinds of references to deploying a service, but not what is necessary to deploy a service consumption module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news is that I have to deploy absolutely no files from the project have to be deployed to the production site.  Everything the web service consumer application needs gets compiled into the application assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for short, but I don't have the answer for you. But you can get this answer yourself. This is the only way Iwould get the answer. Deploy it without them, see if it works. If it doesn't deploy with. If it works, then you know.

Comment: Not exactly.  I suspect I need one or more of the files.  If I follow your advice, then I would never know which files are needed by the client application.  If I do not get an answer, I will probably go through the tedious process of adding and subtracting them, one-by-one until I figure it out.  But someone may already have done that, which would save myself and others the time.

Comment: Wait, to clarify. In my work using web services I have not run into this. I was under the impression this was unique to this service.

Comment: I don't think so.  When I first developed my client for the service last March, I added a web reference instead of a service reference, so this is new to me.